# Mapping an array in my Next JS app not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next JS app I'm getting array and mapping them for the nav bar. but when i do it throws an error of `TypeError: _utils_navigation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...).map is not a function`. my code is as follows.

```
{NavRoutes.map((navs, index) => {
            console.log(navs.title);
            console.log('bhsjvhjvs');
            return (
              <Link href={navs.link}>
            <div className={`${
              router.asPath === navs.link 
              ? "text-active-red"
              : ""
            }`}>{navs.title}</div>
          </Link>
            )
          })}
```

and the array

```
const NavRoutes = [
    {
      title: "HOME",
      link: "/"
    },
    {
      title: "NEWS",
      link: "/news"
    },
    {
      title: "CHANNEL",
      link: "/channels"
    },
    {
      title:"SHOWS",
      link: "/shows"
    },
    {
      title: "SCHEDULE",
      link: "/schedules"
    },
    {
      title: "CONTACT",
      link: "/contact"
    },
]

export default NavRoutes;
```

so how can i work through this?

Comment: Please show some more code for the first codeblock. Where did you import `NavRoutes`? Also, remember that mapped elements need a `key` prop.

Comment: @code my code is in my `../components/navbar.js` and the array is in `../utils/navigations.js` this is my structure.

Comment: Please edit the question with the entire file from which the first codeblock originated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check how you have imported it.
It should be like this

```
import NavRoutes from "../utils/navigations.js";
```

And apart from this, try to console NavRoutes and check you are getting expected value or not.

Comment: I'm importing that exactly without the `.js` extension. but nothing

Comment: @MohammedBekele so what was the problem?

Comment: @code it was confusing, i just had to kill and re run the app.